# ASP.net master pages, web root, and directory structure

Tags: asp.net, iis, master-pages, directory-structure

*I've revised (but not changed) this question for brevity; see [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12237691/revisions) for previous version(s)*

I have an ASP.net website (*non-application, non-MVC*) with the following (*proposed*) file system hierarchy:

[image: Proposed directory structure]

What configuration changes (*if any*) can be made to implement this scheme? Is this possible? I've received the error `Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top` when having targeted `/Site` as the application. I'm wondering if there's a way around this.

As I see it, given the site runs in `C:\www\SiteRoot\` at `http://example.com/`:

```
            PATH                        URL
~           C:\www\SiteRoot\            none
/           C:\www\SiteRoot\Site\       http://example.com/
~/Site      C:\www\SiteRoot\Site\       http://example.com/
/About      C:\www\SiteRoot\Site\About  http://example.com/About/
```

Therefore, `MasterPageFile="~/Site/About.master"` will still resolve correctly,
as will `<img src="/About/ImageInAboutFolder.jpg" />`. Hopefully this sort of configuration is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, no, you can't.

Comment: Plain and simple, eh? Damn. Could you expand on your answer? I'm just curious if there are any recommendations you could make on implementing a similar scheme; for instance, if I had control over the IIS instance, could I configure it such that this or similar was possible? (*if so, I'm firing off a strongly worded ticket to IT*)

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to make the Site folder a web root?

Comment: Well, it's to follow an existing convention, so for organization mostly. I'm considering just moving the master pages to a separate directory, however it would be rather *nice* if this were possible ;) I mentioned URL rewriting; could that be an option?

Comment: If you open the project from the root, then you can view all the subsites at once. I appreciate this may fill you with dread if you have thousands.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Bracketworks Probably because I'm telling you to do what you currently have, by the look of it. Ignore me :)